# Do Locally Contractible, Path-Connected Groups have Accessible Bases?

Tags: gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, topological-groups

Suppose $G$ is a locally contractible, metric, path-connected topological group.  In my particular case, $G$ will be the group of orientation-preserving homeomorphisms of the plane, denoted $Aut(\mathbb{R}^2)$, in the compact-open topology.  In this context, it's the same as the topology of compact convergence.  $G$ is metric since it's a subgroup of the orientation-preserving homeomorphisms of the (compact) sphere, namely the ones fixing infinity.

What I'd like to do is extend these local contractions to global homeomorphisms of $G$.  I feel like this could be impossible in some weird cases, so for my purposes it's sufficient to have the following:

> Does each point have a local basis of contractible neighborhoods
> whose boundaries are path-accessible?

In other words, for $x \in G$, is there an arbitrarily small, contractible nbhd $U$ of $x$ such that for every $y \in \partial(U)$, there is an embedding $f$ of $[0,1]$ into $G \setminus U$ with $f(0) = y$?

It seems like a big ask, but I actually think this is true.  If not, is it at least true for $Aut(\mathbb{R}^2)$?

EDIT: Note that by the comments below, there is some historical issue with the definition of "locally contractible."  The "geometric topologist's sense" is a weaker definition: For each nbhd $U$ of $x$ there is a nbhd $V \subset U$ that deforms to a point in $U$, not necessarily itself.  Especially, $Aut(\mathbb{R}^2)$ may only satisfy the weaker version.  Feel free to use either version for this question, though.  In this case, we'll want the $V$ to have accessible boundary.

Comment: Is it true that each point of $Aut(\mathbb{R}^2)$ has a local base of contractible neighbourhoods (this is not the standard definition of local contractibility)?

Comment: Yes it's true; it's the standard definition as far as I know!  What is your definition?

Comment: A common definition of local contractibility is that for all $x\in U\subseteq X$ ($U$ open) there is $x\in V\subseteq U$ ($V$ open) such that the inclusion $V\subseteq U$ is inessential (so $V$ is deformable in $U$ to a point). As far as I can tell from, say, Kirby-Edwards, this is as much as you can say in general about homeomorphism groups. I looked at Dyer-Hamstrom too for their work on $Aut(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and they seemed to be using the same definition. I'd be interested to know where the stronger condition is established (or if I'm just missing something ;)).

Comment: It's the same, but it's not obvious, as it's special to this situation.  See 1.11 Remark (3) here: https://maths.dur.ac.uk/users/mark.a.powell/cernavskii%20local%20contractibility.pdf  I think the definition you cite was used because it was better-suited to the other topologies (uniform and Whitney/"majorant") he wanted to compare to.

Comment: Now I'm sort of curious how nice a group you can make that satisfies your definition but not the general one, though!  How locally connected can it be before the two definitions are equivalent?  There are a lot of unanswered questions on MSE/MO of this sort of flavor right now, kind of a shame because they're often very attractive.

Comment: Cernavski's remark is that his definition of local contactibility (the identity has a neighbourhood which is deformable in $G$ to a point) is the same as the definition I give above ('the usual definition' cf. Borsuk). This [need not](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87387/well-pointed-space-which-is-not-locally-contractible) be the same as the stronger condition. Cernavski does something in his Proposition B, but tbh I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Proposition B is proving the remark more thoroughly, but also with a compact support requirement (i.e. constant outside an open neighborhood of a compact).  Though it has more consequences than that, I'm not sure of their usefulness when $D \neq \varnothing$.  As you say, prop B also implies the full, simultaneous contractibility of the $\epsilon$-nbhd by isotopy to the identity.  There are various ways to get the compact support; there's also a stretching+shrinking method that 'undoes the kinks and winding', I'll find the paper later.

Comment: You know what, I think you might be right that this is a big issue.  For some reason I was so sure that this was also true for the plane, but I'm beginning to doubt it.  I posted an answer in this thread related to the topic, maybe you can look at it and see if this is the idea?  Or if this isn't a proper way of understanding the obstruction to "full local contractibility":  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4075662/local-contractibility-of-homeomorphism-group-of-mathbbrn/4082725#4082725

Comment: @JohnSamples Your definition of path-accessibility seems to contain some misprints. Probably $g$ should be $x$ and what is the relation of $f$ to $x$ or $g$? Or you just need that each point in the boundary of $U$ is the end-point of some arc in the complement of $U$?

Comment: Sorry yes, $x = g$ but otherwise that's what I want.  The embedding $f$ is related to $x$ only in the sense that I want it for those deformable neighborhoods associated with $x$ as guaranteed by local contractibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your restricted question the answer is affirmative. It follows from the following theorem of [Yagasaki](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0166-8641(99)00130-3):

**Theorem.** For any subpolyhedron $X$ in a connected 2-manifold $M$, the connected component of the group $H_X(M)$ of homeomorphisms of $M$ that are identity on $X$ is an $\ell_2$-manifold.

Comment: Oh, nice!  I believe you that this answers the problem, but can you explain a bit more?  I have to be honest, I can't make heads or tails of this answer x(

Comment: Btw there is also the question about whether this group is "strongly locally contractible," i.e. every point has a local basis of contractible nbhds.  I was told a while back that it was, but now I'm not so sure, and it's hard to prove directly one way or the other.  Any thoughts?  Obviously being homotopy-equiv to the circle doesn't guarantee it, but does "homotopy-equiv to strongly locally contractible" + other properties of $G$ guarantee it?  I was thinking something like taking the symmetrization of the trace of $V$ under the deformation might work if it's true.

Comment: @JohnSamples Maybe this paper on the local contratibility of homeomorphism groups will be of some help? R. Geoghegan, On spaces of homeomorphisms, embeddings and functions – I, Topology 11 (1972), 159–177.

Comment: @JohnSamples What exactly is not clear in my answer?

Comment: Thanks for the ref, will check it out!  As far as the answer, I don't know what an $\ell_2$-manifold is, and don't quite understand how you're using those subgroups $H_X(M)$.  Or is it a trick and $X = \lbrace \infty \rbrace$?  Is this a proof for the accessibility, or the 'strong local contractibility'?

Comment: Is it some sort of Hilbert manifold?  Maybe this is strong enough to imply the global extension of the contraction to all of $G$ continuously?

Comment: @JohnSamples An $\ell_2$-manifold is a paracompact topological space that has a base of the topology consisting of sets homeomorphic to the separable Hilbert space $\ell_2$. So, locally an $\ell_2$-manifold behave like the Hilbert space. This yields all desirable properties of neighborhoods (like accessibility).

Comment: @JohnSamples For the group $Aut(\mathbb R^2)$ one can take $X=\emptyset$ and conclude that $Aut(\mathbb R^2)=H_\emptyset(\mathbb R^2)$. But on the other hand, $Aut(\mathbb R^2)$ can be identified with the group $H_{X}(S^2)$ where $X$ is a singleton in the 2-sphere $S^2$. So, this general result of Yagasaki can be applied in many different ways.

Comment: Ah, haha.  That's even trickier, I like it ;D  Ok, this resolves so many conflicting things I've heard over the past couple days!  I don't think it's well-known that the space is THAT nice, I'm actually kind of surprised to see a paper from 2020.  I thought this was all classical.

Comment: @JohnSamples Actually, it is a classical open problem if $H(M)$ is an $\ell_2$-manifold for any $n$-manifold $M$. The answer is known only in dimension $\le 2$. For higher dimension we only know that the homeomorphism group is locally contractible and stable under multiplication by $\ell_2$. The ANR-property is a wide open question.

Comment: I came into this from plane dynamics/isotopies, I've avoided infinite-dimensional anything my whole life.  Occasionally I've regretted it, this is one of those times because this is all very interesting and beautiful!